# How to convert Sparkr GLM model to native R GLM model

Tags: r, glm, sparkr

I am trying to create the generalized linear model using sparkr "glm" method.

```
df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
linear_model <- spark.glm(df, Sepal_Length ~ Sepal_Width, family = "gaussian")
write.ml(linear_model, '/tmp/linmodel.ml', TRUE)

## Is this possible?
converted_linear_model <- convert_spark_to_R_glm(linear_model)
saveRDS(converted_linear_model, '/tmp/linmodel.rds')
```

Although I can apply the model created directly into the "predict" function of spark ML library but i wanted to use that model inside the native R function.

```
outDf <- dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {
    # converted_linear_model <- readRDS('/tmp/linmodel.rds') # this can help to access the model inside the R worker
    result <- predict(converted_linear_model, x)
    return(result)
})
head(outDf)
```

Is there a way to convert the spark linear model (*linear_model*) to native R linear model (*converted_linear_model*)? Also how to pass it to inside the R function?

**Edited:**
Here is what i have tried along with the error:

CODE

```
# Include spark path
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/dev/spark")
}
library(SparkR)
library(httr)

# Connect to spark master
sc = sparkR.session(master = "spark://dev-Inspiron-7560:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.app.name="TEST ZIP GROUPING"))

# Load the defaulot dataframe
df <- as.DataFrame(iris)

# Create the linear model
linear_model <- spark.glm(df, Sepal_Length ~ Sepal_Width, family = "gaussian")
summary(linear_model)

# fitted values on training data
fitted <- dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {
    r <- predict(linear_model, x)
    return(r)
})

# Print output
head(select(fitted, "Sepal_Length", "prediction"))

# Stop the SparkSession now
sparkR.session.stop()
```

ERROR

```
> # Include spark path
> if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
+   Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/dev/spark")
+ }
> library(SparkR)
> library(httr)
> 
> # Connect to spark master
> sc = sparkR.session(master = "spark://dev-Inspiron-7560:7077", sparkConfig = list(spark.app.name="TEST ZIP GROUPING"))
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: /home/dev/spark
Launching java with spark-submit command /home/dev/spark/bin/spark-submit   sparkr-shell /tmp/RtmpSzkyW9/backend_port378063436025 
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/01/16 17:21:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/16 17:21:37 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, dev-Inspiron-7560 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.181 instead (on interface wlan0)
18/01/16 17:21:37 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
18/01/16 17:21:44 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
> 
> # Load the defaulot dataframe
> df <- as.DataFrame(iris)
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Use Sepal_Length instead of Sepal.Length  as column name
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Use Sepal_Width instead of Sepal.Width  as column name
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Use Petal_Length instead of Petal.Length  as column name
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Use Petal_Width instead of Petal.Width  as column name
> 
> # Create the linear model
> linear_model <- spark.glm(df, Sepal_Length ~ Sepal_Width, family = "gaussian")
18/01/16 17:21:49 WARN optim.WeightedLeastSquares: regParam is zero, which might cause numerical instability and overfitting.
18/01/16 17:21:49 WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
18/01/16 17:21:49 WARN netlib.BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
18/01/16 17:21:49 WARN netlib.LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
18/01/16 17:21:49 WARN netlib.LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
> summary(linear_model)

Deviance Residuals: 
(Note: These are approximate quantiles with relative error <= 0.01)
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.55614  -0.64446  -0.12315   0.53321   2.22255  

Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   6.52622     0.47890  13.6276    0.0000
Sepal_Width  -0.22336     0.15508  -1.4403    0.1519

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.6807844)

    Null deviance: 102.17  on 149  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 100.76  on 148  degrees of freedom
AIC: 372

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1

> 
> # fitted values on training data
> fitted <- dapplyCollect(df, function(x) {
+     r <- predict(linear_model, x)
+     return(r)
+ })
18/01/16 17:21:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 15, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18/01/16 17:21:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 15.0 (TID 16, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18/01/16 17:21:54 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 15.0 (TID 17, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18/01/16 17:21:54 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 18, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

18/01/16 17:21:54 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
18/01/16 17:21:54 ERROR r.RBackendHandler: collect on 21 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:40)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 18, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2390)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec$$anonfun$6.apply(objects.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 18, 192.168.1.181, executor 0): org.apache.spark.SparkException: R computation failed with
 Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
Error in callJMethod(object@jobj, "transform", newData@sdf) : 
  Invalid jobj 18. If SparkR was restarted, Spark operations need to be re-executed.
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.compute(RRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.r.MapPartitionsRWrapper.apply(MapPartitionsRWrapper
> 
> # Print output
> head(select(fitted, "Sepal_Length", "prediction"))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"standardGeneric", "character"’
> 
> # Stop the SparkSession now
> sparkR.session.stop()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and possible error messages. Have you tried to use directly your SparkR `linear_model` in `dapply` and failed?

Comment: @desertnaut I just edited the sample code with iris dataframe. I have tried to directly use the _linear_model_ inside the dapply, but because its inside the R worker its throwing me an error : _Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dapply’ for signature ‘"SparkDataFrame", "function", "missing"’_ .

Other way of passing it would be if i can somehow convert the spark model into a native R model and save it in a .rds file, and later access inside the dapply function.

Comment: Please include the error message (and what led to it) in the body of your post - the comments section is not for such info

Comment: @desertnaut Just included the code and the error that i am getting. Any solution to convert the model or otherwise as well?

Comment: What exactly is your end purpose, for which you feel you need to use `dapplyCollect` instead of simply `predict`? Why you want to use the Spark model in a native R function?